# How to insert function argument that is string to abs() inside dplyr::filter()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to pass PCnumber to the `abs()` function inside `dplyr::filter()` but it resulted in error.
For example:

```
df <- data.frame(PC=rnorm(n = 25, mean = 0, sd = 1))
```

```
foo <- function(x, PCnumber) {
  PCnumber_load0 <- select(x, PCnumber)
  PCnumber_load <-
    filter(PCnumber_load0, (abs(PCnumber) >= mean(abs(PCnumber))))
  PCnumber_load
}
foo(df, PCnumber="PC")
```

Resulting in the following error message.

```
 Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x non-numeric argument to mathematical function
i Input `..1` is `(abs(PCnumber) >= mean(abs(PCnumber)))`.
```

I already tried to change the `PCnumber` inside `abs()` with `cat(PCnumber)`, `{{PCnumber}}`, `!!PCnumber` but not one worked.

Thank you.

Comment: That error occurs when the argument (`PCnumber`) is not numeric. As @MichaelBarrowman's answer demonstrates, you cannot use a string literal in that way, you need to do [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to first take the user-provided argument an turn it into a symbol:

```
library(rlang)

df <- data.frame(PC=rnorm(n = 25, mean = 0, sd = 1))

foo <- function(x, PCnumber) {
  PCnumber <- sym(PCnumber)
  
  PCnumber_load <-
    filter(x, (abs(!!PCnumber) >= mean(abs(!!PCnumber)))) # Then you unquote it with bang bang operator and it's a technic widely used in data masking which is the purpose of tidyverse functions
  
  PCnumber_load
}

foo(df, PCnumber= "PC")

           PC
1   1.1658969
2   0.9449877
3  -2.3434366
4  -1.3040914
5  -1.4638784
6  -0.8324823
7   0.8094797
8   1.4789942
9   1.0667956
10 -0.9972897
11  0.7548202
```

If you had any other question I would be glad to explain more.

Comment: Please note that we use `sym()` function because the user-provided argument is supposed to be a character string, otherwise you could use `enquo()` instead of `sym()` for quoting user-provided arguments.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, your function interprets the `PCnumber` variable as a simple string, which it is. You want it to be converted into the *variable* contained within the data.frame (`x`).

You ned to use `sym()` to convert the string into a *symbol* which can then be inserted using `!!`:

```
foo <- function(x, PCnumber) {
  PCnumber <- sym(PCnumber)
  PCnumber_load0 <- select(x, !!PCnumber)
  PCnumber_load <-
    filter(PCnumber_load0, (abs(!!PCnumber) >= mean(abs(!!PCnumber))))
  PCnumber_load
}
```